# How the "apart from" is used to represent different meanings?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Following the [this web site](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apart_from),

it seems that apart from has two meanings which contradict each other

1. Except for.
2. In addition to; as well as.

When it is used as the 1st meaning, it includes the object that follows the apart from

But it does not include the object when it comes to being used as 2nd meaning.

How can I distinguish them? Is there any difference in usage?

Comment: Context will help you understand. http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/apart-from - http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/apart-from

Comment: There are more example sentences at the [Lomgmans](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/apart-from) site (but these also include the literal usage '[when] separated from: 'The trouble is that they have not learned to be secure and capable apart from their parents.', as well as an example of the MWV 'set apart from'.)